# Watermarking on existing video

Tags: c#, video, watermark, video-editing, video-watermarking

I'm looking for a method to watermarking on a video with C#.

As writing text on it.

Image or text label...

[image]

How can I do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Nreco Video Converter

The Code will look like

```
NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter wrap = new FFMpegConverter();
wrap.Invoke("-i D:\\input.mp4 -i D:\\inputImage.png -filter_complex \"overlay=10:10\" D:\\Output.mp4");
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the great framework from AForge?

http://www.aforgenet.com/

Answer (score 0):

The great people at [Splicer for .Net](http://splicer.codeplex.com/) have already developed some C# code that does what you are looking for, but unfortunately I have heard that it takes a while to complete.

At least this can serve as a starting point if nothing else