# Where to download FFMPEG.exe and use it in C#

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to watermark a video using FFMPEG.
I tried [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32588712/2409701%20)

```
NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter wrap = new FFMpegConverter();
wrap.Invoke("-i D:\\input.mp4 -i D:\\inputImage.png -filter_complex \"overlay=10:10\" D:\\Output.mp4");
```

but it gives error

> ffmpeg: Invalid argument (exit code: 1)

I tried searching if i could use such kind of method(invoke) in AForge, splicer or in other library.

I came across many another questions on stackoverflow  [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268022/process-start-arguments%20)
which uses ffmpeg exe. I don't know where i can find it.

I also found this [link](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/%20) from official ffmpeg website for windows but can not find any such thing

I have just started working on video processing in c# so i am very confused about the concepts kindly help me to get a start.

Comment: NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter will extract the ffmpeg.exe executable if it does not exist. Can your title be missleading? ffmpeg: Invalid argument (exit code: 1) means the executable is there and starts and complains about the arguments..

Comment: @OguzOzgul yes i found the actual problem. there is something wrong in my arguments. Space in path is creating a problem

Comment: Ok, glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Not a programming question (imho). Windows builds: [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). I am not using complex filters. I am using `$path_to_ffmpeg$\bin>ffmpeg.exe -i in.mp4 -vf "movie=watermark.png [w]; [in][w] overlay=10:10 [out]" -acodec copy out.mp4` instead. No need for `NReco.VideoConverter`. Just run as a process. Control the output redirection, escape quotes, watch for spaces in paths, etc...